# How can I do a multiple comparisons test and output the specific groups which have a p-value of less than .05?

Tags: r

I have multiple data frames, each with a column of ages for various samples. The following data frames only have the column of interest(age)

```
df1 <- c(34, 25, 45, 6, 67, 12)
df2 <- c(31, 23, 71, 19)
df3 <- c(12, 45, 42, 89, 12)
df4 <- c(34, 37, 23)
```

If I run

```
results <- dunn.test(list(df1, df2, df3, df4))
```

it outputs the p-values for each of the 6 possible comparisons. Only if one of these p-values is less than .05, how can I have it output which specific data frames it is coming from (for example, df1 and df2 comparison has p-value of .01, so I want it to print df1, df2). It outputs the "comparisons" in the results data frame but it would be better if I can get the specific data frame which it comes from.

The data I am working on is with many lists similar to list(df1, df2, df3, df4) so I am looking for a general solution.

If there is anything that you would like clarified, please ask!

Comment: What does `dunn.test` come from? That doesn't appear to be a base R function.

Comment: If you are doing multiple comparisons,  shouldn't you use the [Bonferroni correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction) ?

Comment: @MrFlick It seems to come from package `dunn.test`. But running it on the OP's data doesn't give any p-value below 0.05, `results$P` outputs `[1] 0.4373240 0.3244279 0.3977284 0.4123293 0.4713834 0.4352448`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.

Name your data frames

```
df <- list("a" = df1, "b" = df2, "c" = df3, "d" = df4)
```

and then use `?sapply()`

```
result <- sapply(df, function(x){
    dunn.test(x)
})
```

Look at the attributes of `result`

```
str(result)
List of 20
 $ : num 5
 $ : num [1:15] 0.378 -0.378 -0.756 1.134 0.756 ...
 $ : num [1:15] 0.353 0.353 0.225 0.128 0.225 ...
 $ : num [1:15] 0.353 0.353 0.225 0.128 0.225 ...
 $ : chr [1:15] "1 - 2" "1 - 3" "2 - 3" "1 - 4" ...
 $ : num 3
 $ : num [1:6] 0.548 -0.548 -1.095 1.095 0.548 ...
 $ : num [1:6] 0.292 0.292 0.137 0.137 0.292 ...
 $ : num [1:6] 0.292 0.292 0.137 0.137 0.292 ...
 $ : chr [1:6] "1 - 2" "1 - 3" "2 - 3" "1 - 4" ...
 $ : num 4
 $ : num [1:10] -1.147 -0.688 0.459 -1.606 -0.459 ...
 $ : num [1:10] 0.1257 0.2456 0.3232 0.0541 0.3232 ...
 $ : num [1:10] 0.1257 0.2456 0.3232 0.0541 0.3232 ...
 $ : chr [1:10] "1 - 2" "1 - 3" "2 - 3" "1 - 4" ...
 $ : num 2
 $ : num [1:3] -0.707 0.707 1.414
 $ : num [1:3] 0.2398 0.2398 0.0786
 $ : num [1:3] 0.2398 0.2398 0.0786
 $ : chr [1:3] "1 - 2" "1 - 3" "2 - 3"
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 5 4
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:5] "chi2" "Z" "P" "P.adjusted" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

then go

`attr(result,"dimnames")[1]` for value labels or

`attr(result,"dimnames")[2]` for variable names